# ExecutorService.awaitTermination(timeout,unit) continue to run even after timeout

Tags: java

I have 2 classes.  a POJO and main.

POJO Class

```
public class Processor implements Runnable{

private int id;

public Processor(int id)
{
    this.id = id;

}
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Started ...."+ id);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Stoped ..." + id);
}

}
```

The main Class

```
 public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5;i++)
    {
        executor.submit(new Processor(i));


    }
    executor.shutdown();
    System.out.println("All tasks Submits");
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Intrupted or Timeout");

    }
    System.out.println("all Tasks completed");
}
```

}

When i run this Code i get the output of

```
Started ....0
All tasks Submits
Started ....1
all Tasks completed
Stoped ...1
Started ....2
Stoped ...0
Started ....3
Stoped ...2
Started ....4  
Stoped ...3
Stoped ...4
```

But as per my understanding once an timeout occur it should fire an interrupted exception and returned. But why its continue to ran even after it exit from TRY block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets turn to the javadoc for [awaitTermination](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

*Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first.*

In other words: calling that method doesn't mean that already submitted jobs aren't executed any more. So the flaw is within your assumptions.

Your main will run into that timeout, but just because you then print "all tasks completed" doesn't make that a true statement. Those submitted tasks are completed, well, when they are completed. And not before!

So, if you want to really "stop" everything, you should be experimenting with [shutdownNow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()) instead.

Answer (score 1):

As @GhostCat said , `awaitTermination` gets thread blocked for given time , if you want to cause exception while blocking you can do it like this blow :

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
    public void run() {
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    exec.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        System.out.println("start ...");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("end ...");
        }
    });

    exec.shutdown();

    try {
        exec.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("awaitTermination");
    }
    System.out.println("main ended");
    };
};
t.start();
Thread.sleep(10);;
t.interrupt();
```

run this code in a main method .